# Display values in rows of four items

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Was hoping for a little help if possible.

I am trying to display content in rows of four items per row by looping through a collection but it is not displaying properly as it is.

To me it feels right.

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.T.Count(); i++)
 {
if (i % 4 == 0)
{
    @:<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <div class="post">
                <div class="post-img-content-4">
                    <img src="images/u14.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                    <span class="post-title">
                        <b>@Model.T[i].TopicName</b><br />
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


}
else if (i % 4 == 1)
{
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <div class="post">
            <div class="post-img-content-4">
                <img src="images/u14.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                <span class="post-title">
                    <b>@Model.T[i].TopicName</b><br />
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
else if (i % 4 == 2)
{
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <div class="post">
            <div class="post-img-content-4">
                <img src="images/u14.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                <span class="post-title">
                    <b>@Model.T[i].TopicName</b><br />
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
else if (i % 4 == 3)
{
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <div class="post">
            <div class="post-img-content-4">
                <img src="images/u14.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                <span class="post-title">
                    <b>@Model.T[i].TopicName</b><br />
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

}
else if (i % 4 == 0 && i != 0)
{
 @:</div><div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <div class="post">
            <div class="post-img-content-4">
                <img src="images/u14.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                <span class="post-title">
                    <b>@Model.T[i].TopicName</b><br />
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   }

  }
</div>
```

How can I display these items in rows of four items per row?

Regards

Comment: As a side remark, `<div>` has no semantic meaning and could probably be replaced with more semantic tags like `<li>`  or `<article>`; The use of `<br>` is also semantically incorrect, better use CSS properties to put some space between elements, and you probably also use `<b>` tag only to get bold text, which is also a bad practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code should be simple, you just have to display all the post div. The column system of bootstrap will set their width to display four items a row

```
<div class="row">
  @for (var i = 0; i < Model.T.Count(); i++) {
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <div class="post">
            <div class="post-img-content-4">
                <img src="images/u14.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                <span class="post-title">
                    <b>@Model.T[i].TopicName</b><br />
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  }
</div>
```

Comment: Hahaha...thanks bootstrap!!, didnt even think of that!

Answer (score 2):

This div `<div class="row">` is never really closed because of your IF condition.

Example, I have 0 as the value of *i*, this is the initial creation of your `<div class="row">` which is correct so far.

But then we get to 4 as the value of of *i*, what it does is it creates another `<div class="row">` without really closing the first `<div class="row">` because your closing tag is in the `else if` condition and your code will not enter that last `else if` condition.

To explain, your code will never reach that last else if condition `else if (i % 4 == 0 && i != 0)` because it will always fall into that first `if (i % 4 == 0)` because it satisfies the condition immediately, and it will not bother to check any of those ELSE IF statements if it has already satisfied the primary IF condition.

A suggestion would be to put the closing div tag for `<div class="row">` at the `else if (i % 4 == 3)` code block